# How do I use JQuery inside an object constructor in my own javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, namespaces

I can't even find a hint of an answer to this question anywhere, so maybe I'm totally barking up the wrong tree...

I'm making a javascript namespace, inside of which I am putting a constructor function:

```
var SEP=SEP||{};

SEP.person=function(name)
{
    this.name=name
    this.sayName=sayName

    function sayName()
    {
        return this.name;
        $(document).ready
        (
            function()
            {
                $('body').css('background', 'red');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then I am calling the function from the HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 10.5" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="libraries/jquery/javascript/jquery-1.11.0-min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/sep/javascript/sep.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<script>
    var bob=new SEP.person("bob");
    word=bob.sayName();
    document.write(word);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question one is, why doesn't this work?
Question two is how can I make it work?
Question three is, if I want to make a more involved constructor, with JQuery peppered thoughout, do I need to do the document ready thing over and over, or is there a better way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't mean why the person object should change the background color, but you can rethink your hierarchy, think to jQuery as dependency, so you should provide your namespace/object to a reference to that dependency

Comment: This code is just the first lines that came into my head to test the validity of the method. It's not a real part of the project I'm doing... so, person saying their name, background turning red, it's all good! :) How would I provide a reference to JQuery in my namespace or object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your constructor is working fine. But you should not use `document.write` in your code. Instead you can append the value to a html tag, using either `.append()` `.html()` or `.text()` methods. Also there should be a small change in your `sayName()` method, Css should apply before `return`. Otherwise it will not hit on those lines of code.

```
var SEP = SEP || {};

SEP.person = function (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.sayName = sayName

    function sayName() {
        $('body').css('background', 'red');
        return this.name;
    }
}

var bob = new SEP.person("bob");
word = bob.sayName();
$("span").text(word);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/63/)

Comment: Hahaha... D'oh! I can't believe I missed that. And, yeah, the document.write was just to quickly test the response - I wouldn't actually do that in real life. OK, so this works, but what do I do about all the rest of the JQuery I want to use dotted about the constructor? Surely I wouldn't have to write the $(document).ready function out each time I want to use JQuery? Is there a better way that I am missing? Thanks for your speedy and excellent reply, btw.